# Triggering a handler from a role once

Tags: ansible

I have all my inventory and roles defined. One of the roles takes care of the database status, and has a handler that triggers a cleanup any time the tasks in the role touch the database.

Now I am in the need of cleaning up the databases on all database nodes on demand, naturally I would like to use the handler that already knows what to do.

I've started a playbook for it, importing the required roles, however, it does look like I cannot just notify a handler.

```
   - hosts: db_updaters
     roles:
       - db_updater
     tasks:
       - name: Run DB cleanup
         notify: Cleanup DB
```

When I execute that playbook I get

```
ERROR: 'action' or 'local_action' attribute missing in task "Run DB cleanup"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
- name: notify handler
  debug: msg="notify handler"
  notify: Cleanup DB
```

If that doesn't work then something like this should:

```
- name: notify handler
  command: /bin/true
  notify: Cleanup DB
```

Comment: I've used the `/bin/true` variant before. Adding a `delegate_to: localhost` improves speed a bit.